# What's the most efficient way to copy/clone the structure of a JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, json

I guess the title is quite trivial. Basically what I want is shomething like `mysqldump ... --no-data ...`. For example, I have a json object like this:

```
{ "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2",
  "key3" : {
      "key3a" : 1,
      "key3b" : 2
  },
  "key4" : "value3"
}
```

And what I want is and empty object with the same structure, like this:

```
{ "key1" : null,
  "key2" : null,
  "key3" : {
      "key3a" : null,
      "key3b" : null
  },
  "key4" : null
}
```

Comment: Basically you want a copy of the object with null in place of strings and numbers, right?

Comment: you have to create an object contains all the tags of the json and fill the values of the object with null values and the serialize this object

Answer (score 1):

What you want is similar to what is usually called "deep cloning", you just seem to want to return `null` for what isn't an object. The simplest way to do this kind of cloning is with a recursive function :

```
function deepAutomnClone(o){
  if (typeof o !== 'object') return null;
  var c = {};
  for (k in o) c[k] = deepAutomnClone(o[k]);
  return c;
}
```

You would call it like this :

```
var obj = { "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2",
  "key3" : {
      "key3a" : 1,
      "key3b" : 2
  },
  "key4" : "value3"
};
console.log(deepAutomnClone(obj));
```

Now, you weren't very precise in your question. You might want to modify the function depending for example on the desired handling of arrays.

Last thing : Please note that what you have isn't a "JSON object", because JSON is a text based exchange format. This is a plain JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with support for reseting Arrays in additions to Objects.
It also avoids setting to null the properties of the object that would have been inherited.

```
function cloneAndReset(obj) {

    var res = null;

    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        res = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                res[i] = cloneAndReset(obj[i]);
        }
        return res;
    }

    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        res = {};
        for (p in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {                            
                res[p] = cloneAndReset(obj[p]);
            } 
        }
    } 

    return res;
}
```